# Switching between iPhone ViewControllers programmatically

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have several view controllers for various parts of a game I am working on, let's call them screens 1,2,3,4.

I would like to be able to start the game up in screen 1, then show 2, 3, 4 and then go back to screen 1 and start all over again (sometimes I want to leave out #3, etc). I have managed to get this functionality with the UITabBarController but I couldn't figure out how to hide the tab control itself. If I hid the actual control it would just display a white bar in its place. If I tried to resize the view it worked on the first screen, then the others appeared to be twice the screen size (set in viewWillAppear):

[[self view] setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

Has anybody managed to get this sort of thing working? Would I be able to use a navigation controller to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `UINavigationController` for this because for your purpose this can be done with `UINavigationController` instead of `UITabBarController`.

But if you want to continue with `UITabBarController` then you can hide your `UITabBarController` by calling this method in your `app delegate`:

```
- (void) hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 480, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height)];
        } 
        else 
        {
            [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, 480)];
        }

    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly! This has taken me hours to track down, thank you VERY much for your help!